# Creating Custom AuthorizeAttribute in Web API (.Net Framework)

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, authorize-attribute

I'm using OAuth2.0 Owin (password grant) in my WebAPI.My initial token Response is like below

```
{
    "access_token": "_ramSlQYasdsRTWEWew.....................",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 17999,
    "permissions": {
        "user": [
            "Add",
            "Update",
            "Delete"
        ],
        "Product": [
            "Read",
            "Create"
        ]
    }
}
```

I've [customized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49722037/7073340) the response by creating a new Key called `permissions` which hold the privileges for the corresponding user.

From here I need to validate each Request from my `Resource server`,by checking whether the user has enough permissions to call the API using Authorize Attribute.

I found a similar example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43788693/7073340) where it deals with Dot net Core, which is not suitable for my case.

The difficult part is that the `permission` JSON Key is itself making a complex with `ArrayList`

```
[CustomAuthorize(PermissionItem.Product, PermissionAction.Read)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(Index);
    }

public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute {
    public AuthorizeAttribute (PermissionItem item, PermissionAction action) {
        //Need to initalize the Permission Enums
    }
    public override void OnAuthorization (HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        //Code to get the value from Permissions ArrayList and compare it with the Enum values
    }
}
```

The above is the idea I'm having. But due to the complexity of the `Permissions` Key and Enum comparison I'm couldn't able to move forward.

Also, there is a question like If the permission for User is Add as well as Update means I need to create two Attribute conditions before my Controller.

Like

```
[CustomAuthorize(PermissionItem.User, PermissionAction.Add)]
[CustomAuthorize(PermissionItem.User, PermissionAction.Update)]
```

Which leads to adding more lines of Attributes. So Is there is any way to make it as in a single Conditions with `|` separated?

```
[CustomAuthorize(PermissionItem.User, PermissionAction.Update|PermissionAction.Add)]
```

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you allow your CustomAuthorize constructor to have multiple Permission actions.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly PermissionAction[] permissionActions;

    public CustomAuthorize(PermissionItem item, params PermissionAction[] permissionActions)
    {
        this.permissionActions = permissionActions;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var currentIdentity = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
        if (!currentIdentity.IsAuthenticated) {
            // redirect to access denied page
        }

        var userName = currentIdentity.Name;
        // step 1 : retrieve user object

        // step 2 : retrieve user permissions

        // step 3 : match user permission(s) agains class/method's required premissions

        // step 4 : continue/redirect to access denied page
    }
}
```

And you'll annotate your class with:
`[CustomAuthorize(PermissionItem.User, PermissionAction.Update, PermissionAction.Add)]`

I'm not sure, what does OP want to achieve here. If you are relying on HTTP request to provide access rights then that is A BIG SECURITY HOLE. On each request you should retrieve user's access right information from the database and then match is against the required permission of the class/method.

As a rule of thumb you should not rely on request object to tell you what are the permissions that current user have. You should retrieve them from the datastore.

**My Implementation of CustomAttribute**

```
public class CustomAuthorize : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly PermissionAction[] permissionActions;

    public CustomAuthorize(PermissionItem item, params PermissionAction[] permissionActions)
    {
        this.permissionActions = permissionActions;
    }

    protected override Boolean IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var currentIdentity = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity;
        if (!currentIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        var userName = currentIdentity.Name;
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<AppUser>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<AppUser>(userStore);
            var user = userManager.FindByName(userName);

            if (user == null)
                return false;

            foreach (var role in permissionActions)
                if (!userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, Convert.ToString(role)))
                    return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the actual logic part to do the comparison for the Permissions Enum with the Permission ArrayList.

Comment: I'm getting the user's access rights from Database only. Could you please explain the Step 3 in detail. I need the actual logic for that

Answer (score 2):

We have created below API filter for authentication.

Here, "SecretToken", "MerchantKey" this two key passing in API request. we are validating this two from database using "IsValidMerchant" function.

**IsValidMerchant** this function direct connect with database table where respective value are store

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext actionContext)
{
  const string secretTokenName = "SecretToken";
  const string merchentKeyName = "MerchantKey";
  bool isValid = false;

  if (!actionContext.Filters.Any(item => item is IAllowAnonymousFilter))
    {
     CPServiceResponse response = new CPServiceResponse();
     var secretToken = actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[secretTokenName].FirstOrDefault();
     var merchentKey = actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[merchentKeyName].FirstOrDefault();

      isValid = this.IsValidMerchant(merchentKey, secretToken,_productCode);

       if (isValid == false)
        {
          response.Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
          response.Message = Hegic.Shared.Resource.Common.UnauthorizedRequestError;
          actionContext.Result = new JsonResult("")
                {
                    Value = new { Status = response }
                };
         }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make us of flags and binary operations to allow you to | the different operations together.

The following code shows a small example of how it could be done

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        CustomAuthorizeAttribute customAuthorizeAttribute = (CustomAuthorizeAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Test), typeof(CustomAuthorizeAttribute));

        customAuthorizeAttribute.Test();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[CustomAuthorize(PermissionActions = PermissionAction.Add | PermissionAction.Delete)]
public class Test {

}

public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute {
    public PermissionAction PermissionActions { get; set; }

    public void Test() {
        if ((PermissionActions & PermissionAction.Add) == PermissionAction.Add) Console.WriteLine("Add");
        if ((PermissionActions & PermissionAction.Delete) == PermissionAction.Delete) Console.WriteLine("Delete");
        if ((PermissionActions & PermissionAction.Update) == PermissionAction.Update) Console.WriteLine("Update");
    }
}

public enum PermissionAction {
    Add = 1,
    Update = 2,
    Delete = 4
}
```

Which yields the following output

[image]